# Correlation matrix that counts intersection between variables

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with ID, and some binary variables. i want to create a correlation matrix that counts intersections,ie. if var1 and var2 have 20 ID each with 1, then var1,var2 is 20 (same var2,var1), the diagonal is simply sum(col)

for example:

```
ID <- c(100,101,102,104)
var1 <- c(1,1,1,1)
var2 <- c(1,0,0,1)
var3 <- c(1,1,0,0)
var4 <- c(0,0,0,1)
```

i expect the output to be:

```
vars var1 var2 var3 var4
var1    4    2    2    1
var2    2    2    1    1
var3    2    0    2    0
var4    1    1    0    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form a matrix `m` from the `var` columns and multiply its transpose by itself, i.e. `t(m) %*% m` or use `crossprod` as shown below:

```
m <- cbind(var1, var2,var3, var4)
crossprod(m)
```

giving:

```
     var1 var2 var3 var4
var1    4    2    2    1
var2    2    2    1    1
var3    2    1    2    0
var4    1    1    0    1
```